# numerical methods for discontinuous ODEs

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

Greetings,
what are state of art methods for numerical solution of ODEs with discontinuous right side?
I'm mostly interested piecewise-smooth right side functions, e.g. sign.

Comment: You may want to ask this question at scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: One place to look is the papers of David E. Stewart. The main application area he works in is rigid body dynamics.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the papers of Calvo, Montijano and Randez. Also the papers of Dieci and Lopez.

Comment: Maybe you could expand a bit -- or at least provide complete references to the papers you mention?